# Installation Problems

Tags: installation

I have a Medion desktop 32-bit PC running on Windows Vista built in. Windows will not let me install Ubuntu 11.10 from disk or installer. I keep getting an error message saying that I need to insert the boot disk into a hard disk (When the CD is already in the DVD-ROM drive)?

I have managed to bypass this error message but I cannot get Wubi to install Ubuntu as an application in Windows either. The installation crashes near the end with a message saying that there is an error log message I can't get at.

To complicate matters Windows Vista is missing part of its `DLL` and `CHKPSK` files (No idea why). I don't know if this is relevant but it may have something to do with it.

I can get a very slow Ubuntu 11.10 live demo going from turning PC on with CD in DVD-ROM drive, but I am a bit reluctant to set up a dual boot from the live demo as I am not sure that I would be able to completely uninstall Ubuntu (Removing hard drive partitions) if I have to in future.

Answer (score 1):

Uninstalling Ubuntu completely is easy. First Google hit was this one:
 [How To Safely Uninstall Ubuntu From A Windows Dual-Boot PC](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/how-to-safely-uninstall-ubuntu-in-windows-dual-boot-environment/) and there are lots of others ...

Speed of the demo is highly depending on the performance of the CD-Drive, did you try a USB Disk?

BTW, why 11.10 and not 12.04

Comment: I will try 12.04 and see what happens. Vista doesnt give my admin rights nor do I have a Windows Boot disk so I will try this link to prepare for any future uninstalls http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/nongeeks-guide-safely-uninstall-ubuntu-dualbooting-machine/